# Hibernate scope in the Grails BuildConfig.groovy

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-2.0

According to the Grails [hibernate plugin page](http://grails.org/plugins/tag/hibernate), the scope of the hibernate should be `compile`. But when I create a new Grails app, the BuildConfig.groovy is using the `runtime` scope:

```
runtime ":hibernate:3.6.10.6" // or ":hibernate4:4.1.11.6"
```

I am using Grails 2.3.4 and I am just wondering why it is in the `runtime` scope instead of the `compile` scope.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your application, for majority of programs `runtime` is sufficient, however, if you have some specific code that relies on hibernate then you probably need to use `compile`.

From [Jeff Brown](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.groovy.grails.user/146139) :

> Most applications will get away with expressing a runtime dependency
>   on the hibernate plugin.  If you are writing any code that directly
>   references classes provided by the plugin then you would need a
>   compile time dependency.  That isn't a common thing.